# Property 'click' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: javascript

`item[i].click();` should click the element but its not and displaying error **"Property 'click' does not exist on type 'string'"** can someone please help me why `click()` is not working. Code:

```
var ls = element.all(by.xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-1']/li"));
ls.getText().then(function(items) {

  for (var i = 0; i <= items.length; i++) {

    if (items[i] == "Algeria") {
      console.log(items[i]);
      items[i].click();

      browser.sleep(5000);
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: In this case the error is about as informative as it could be! `item[i]` is a string, as you acknowledge when comparing it: `items[i] == "Algeria"`. You're attempting `"Algeria".click()`, which is not valid because a `string` does not have a `.click()` method.

Comment: Try getting rid of `getText()` initially so the `items` are not of type `string`. Later on, in if condition, you can check like `items[i].getText() == "Algeria"` and `click` on `item` as it would be a HTML node probably.

Comment: do you use `async/await` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

As @Tyler pointed out in the comments that a string does not have `click()` method. What you need is to click the `li` element.

To perform the click action, in the above snippet substitute `items[i].click()` with
`ls[i].click()`

Hope this helps :)